# How to identify all the vowels in a string which is entered by a user

Tags: c, string

Some weird error comes up after I enter a string.  Any help would be appreciated. What I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    int i;
    char line[100];

    printf("Enter a string: \n");
    gets(line);

    for (i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (line[i] == 'a' || line[i] == 'e' || line[i] == 'i' || line[i] == 'o' || line[i] == 'u' || line[i] == 'A' || line[i] == 'E' || line[i] == 'I' || line[i] == 'O' || line[i] == 'U')
        {
            puts(line[i]);
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Details, man, details ...

Comment: Turn on full warnings. The argument to `puts()` must be `char*`, but `line[i]` is a `char`. You want `putc()`.

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x0f5067cf (msvcr100d.dll) in assignmen5.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xffffffcc. And another code window pops up with a bunch of code

Comment: As Barmar says: you are trying to use a vowel as a memory address: hence the access violation.

Comment: I tried using put c but it gives error: too few arguments for call

Comment: @DaftTommy I guess that `putchar` was meant, which goes to `stdout`, whereas `putc` goes to a file stream that needs to passed as another argument. Please get accustomed to reading man pages. But you could have used `putc` like this `putc(line[i], stdout);`

Comment: Do you need help with the algorithm or with your compilation/runtime issues?

Answer (score 1):

`void main()` is not a valid entry point. You probably meant `int main(void)`.

`line[i]` in `puts(line[i]);` isn't a `char *`, let alone a pointer to a string; it's just a character. This is most likely to cause problems.

`system("pause");` is annoying for end users, non-portable and potentially dangerous. Consider using your IDE to place a break-point on your `return 0;` statement, when you insert that. That way your end users won't be bothered by unnecessary pauses in their scripts, error messages about unknown commands or worse, security breaches due to a malicious *pause.sh* being placed somewhere...

Comment: `void main()` is perfectly valid in some systems, most notably freestanding ones. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/584518. Though of course the presence of `system()` does suggest that this is a hosted system. Even still, the C99/C11 standards are unclear about which forms of main() that are allowed even for hosted systems.